# How to enable gThumb raw support?

Tags: raw, photo-management

gThumb supports viewing raw images. I tried to view images of my new Panasonic Lumix, but gThumb displays only a generic image icon instead of a picture.

Is this a problem of my gThumb installation (I thought raw support is built-in?) or can't gThumb handle Panasonics *.rw2?

I'm using gThumb 3.4.3 on elementaryOs 0.4 (Loki) [based on Ubuntu 16.04]

Edit:

- `dcraw -e myphoto.rw2` extracts an preview image, so there is one.
- geeqie shows the embedded image as expected

So, it's a problem with gThumb. How can I solve it? I would like to use gThumb instead of shotwell or geeqie.

Comment: Alternative: Use geeqie. But both programs don't show the RAW, but the internal JPEG preview.

Comment: Installed geeqie. It shows the internal JPEG, but gThumb doesn't. Strange. Nevertheless I'd like to use gThumb…